# Newman-Jenkins-Single sign on (SSO) Integration

Tags: node.js, jenkins, single-sign-on, postman, newman

In my company we have API's which are protected behind Single sign on (Siteminder). To get access to the API we must sign in from browser. 
I logged in manually from chrome browser and used interceptor in postman so that postman can intercept the cookies and use it for subsequent API calls (basically to run the collection). 
However when I am trying to run via Jenkins (Newman) its not working. Not sure how I can pass cookies(SSO data) to jenkins so that I can test end to end.
Please help!!
Thank you,
Appreciate your help